# How to handle looping twice in data frame using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

here's the data frame looks like,

this the data, in case if you wanna try it
[link data from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mdmahmudulhasansuzan/students-adaptability-level-in-online-education)

[image]

and then here's the code that looks like

```
total_data = (len(data_high))
for column in data_high:
  data_type= (data_high[column].value_counts())
  for y in np.array(data_type.index):
      for x in data_type.values:
        average = round((x/total_data)*100,2)
        print(y, average)
```

and then here's the result
[image]

I wanted to loop each value in each column so I used the nested looping, but here's the problem the index are looped twice, how could I handle this

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with these results?

Comment: I'm trying to print the average percentage on each column, so basically, it supposed to be like this
Boy 71.0
Girl 29.0 ... and so on

Comment: Something like this `df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True).mul(100).round(2).unstack().dropna()` ?

Comment: i don't know what you're trying to explain, maybe yes, but the problem here is
please look at the table and the result
so its printed twice but it was wrong printed

Comment: it was supposed to be like Boy 71.0 Girl 29.0 instead of Boy 71.0 Boy 29.0 Girl 71.0 Girl 29.0

Comment: please help me, i have to finish this tomorrow

Comment: Can you explain why 71 29 percent?

Comment: its from average = round((x/total_data)*100,2), x = total data that appears total_data = all of data, which means here Boy = (71 / 100 )* 100

Answer (score 0):

[set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) will only contain unique items. If you put your indices into a set, then it only do each unique index once

Comment: I don't get it, but yeah I'll check the documentation